# Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I am coding a translation app and this error is persisting. 
Here is the code, PLEASE help!

RAW CODE 1

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"; //Defining EXTRA MESSAGE
    public static Boolean hisCheck;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.his);

    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
        if(isChecked){
            hisCheck = true; 
        }
        else {
            hisCheck = false; 
        }
    }


    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.robertb.TRANSLATED");
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

RAW CODE 2

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String input = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] outputS = new String[500];
    Boolean check = MyActivity.hisCheck;
   // output[0] = "There are no detected gender specific words within your submitted message";
    int j = 0;
    String outputFinal;;

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lines2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();


 //goodwords array
    try {
        InputStream goodIs = null;
        if(check){
        goodIs = assetManager.open("goodwords.txt");
        }
        if(check){
            goodIs = assetManager.open("goodwordshis.txt");
            }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(goodIs));

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            lines2.add(line);

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  //badwords array
    try {
        InputStream badIs = null; 
        if(!check){
        badIs = assetManager.open("badwords.txt");
        }if(check){
         badIs = assetManager.open("badwordshis.txt");
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(badIs));
        String line1;

        while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            lines.add(line1);

        }
        String[] arrayBad = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] arrayGood = lines2.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] arrayBad = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    String[] words = input.split("\\W");



    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; ++i1){
         for(int i = 0; i < arrayBad.length; ++i)
         {
             if(words[i1].equalsIgnoreCase(arrayBad[i])){
                 output.add(arrayBad[i] + " = " + arrayGood[i]);

             }
         }
    } 


        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();


    for( String s : output) {
        out.append( s  + "\n");
        }
    if(output.isEmpty()){
        out.append("There are no detected gender specific words within your submitted message");
    }
    outputFinal = out.toString();
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(outputFinal);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);


    }
 }
```

LOGCAT

```
    11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865): Process: com.example.android, PID: 28865
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.Translated}: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:120)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:57)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at com.example.android.Translated.onCreate(Translated.java:51)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-06 19:55:40.031: E/AndroidRuntime(28865):    ... 10 more
```

If you want me to sift through this and return only the important Boolean parts, then I can do that. Just ask. It seems like a made a pretty basic error, and I really really need help on this. Thanks! Any ideas where I need to add in a  if(num != null), or if I even need to?

Comment: Logcat output, please.

Comment: I am guessing it is because your Boolean hisCheck member variable is not initialized.

Comment: Why are you using `Boolean` rather than `boolean`?

Comment: What line is it crashing at?  You should see this in the logcat.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Could you please elaborate??

Comment: @guruguru32: Well, your stack trace points to a different issue than what is mentioned in the title of your quesiton.   According to the stack trace, you are trying to open an asset file that doesn't exist and then subsequently trying to create an InputStreamReader with it.

Comment: Yep, that got fixed when I changed my Boolean to primitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing information through intent then use 
`startActivityForResult(intent)` instead of `startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this line is absolutely correct `com.robertb.TRANSLATED` ?

And what you want to do in this?

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

And finally, have you defined this new activity in androidManifest?

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm until I added this extra button, which simply adds some words to the translation.